# Swift Code Beginner... If-Statement Expected Declaration

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm trying to build a simple app to sharpen my beginner's skills in Swift but I don't understand what type of Expected Declaration is needed?

Here is the code:

```
//Code starts here
        
var weight = Double()
var height = Double()
var bmi = Double()
            
func findBMI() -> Double {
    return weight / (height * height)
}
    
var userBMI = Double()
if userBMI <= 15 {
    print("")
}
```

The Expected Declaration is @ `if userBMI <= 15 {`

I have been changing my code over and over again but I haven't found the solution yet. Can anybody help and tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't add code (statements, operations etc) at the top level like that, it needs to be inside a function. Only declarations can be at the top level and hence the error "Expected Declaration"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a little mistake you cannot use if statements at top level

```
var weight = Double()
var height = Double()
var bmi = Double()
            
func findBMI() -> Double {
    return weight / (height * height)
}
    
var userBMI = Double()

//use if conditions in a function
func ifcheck() {
   if userBMI <= 15 {
    print("Now check is working")
   }
}
```

You have to write conditions and use variables in a function only like above.If you have further questions, you can ask Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are in Swift playground, statements like `if` can be only within a function/method.